# How to calculate the java heap required

Tags: java

I have always given an assumed heap size to my application  and while the app is running, I monitor and modify / tune the heap size.

Is there a way in which I can calculate the initial heap required more or less accurately.

Comment: Using a profiler identify typical number of domain objects your application operate. This will give you an idea how heap should be changed for some other nr of domain objects you expect (e.g., if you have 1K 'users' currently you'll need 10x heap if you expect ten-fold grow of users).

Comment: I think the profiler will calculate only the loaded domain objects(of currently active use cases), I guess a better approach would be to identify the java object size of popular usecases * estimate of the number of users at peak load..i am expecting something in these lines..

Answer (score 0):

For the best performance in a Java EE style environment, i.e. when the application is meant to be running for very long periods of time (months or weeks), then it is best to set the minimum and maximum heap size to be the same.

The best way to size the heap in this case is to gather data on how your application runs over time. With a weeks worth of [verbose GC log](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmpt), we can import that data into [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer). Looking at the troughs of the graph, we can take an average and see the minimum retained set after each garbage collection. This is the amount of data, on average, kept in the heap for normal running. So any heap size should be at least that level. Since we're setting minimum and maximum to the same here, we need to add more space to compensate for spikes. How much to add depends on your use case, but somewhere between 25-35% is a start.

With this method, always remember to keep monitoring your heap and GC behaviour using verbose GC (which is recommended by Oracle to run even in production).

**Important:** This is assuming that your application is an always-on type of application. If you're considering a desktop java application, then the behaviour will be very very different and this should **not** be seen as a reliable method in that case. As @juhist said in his/her answer, just the maximum should be set and the JVM will handle the rest.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you monitor and modify / tune the heap size?

Java has been designed in a way that the heap automatically grows to the needed size as long as the maximum heap size is large enough. You shouldn't modify the heap size manually at all.

I would rely on the automatic Java algorithms for adjusting the heap size and just specify the maximum heap size at program startup. You should take into account how many `java` processes you're running in parallel when deciding the maximum heap size.